# How can I display special characters in jQuery Autocomplete UI?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

Hi I'm trying to get special characters like ëéäá to show up in my autocomplete. For example the letter ë shows up as & # 2 3 5 ; (without the spaces).

I'm creating a php array which I json_encode. I can create the json with both ë (html_entity_decode) and & # 2 3 5 ; (without the spaces) in the object. When I create the json object with ë it doesn't show up in the autocomplete.

My autocomplete function looks as follow:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(function() {
     <?php echo "var availableCustomers = " . $this->searchCustomer . ";\n"; ?>
     $( "#customerAutocomplete" ).autocomplete({
     delay: 0,
     source: availableCustomers,
     select: function(event, ui) {
        window.location.href = '/customer/look-customer/deb/' + ui.item.deb;
         }
      });
     });        
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You would have to override the render method so that it uses .html instead of .text.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks. But how can I render that array as .html?

Comment: I was looking for it but couldn't quickly find it, it's definitely been documented somewhere before

Comment: Here's a demo of it working, http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#folding

Answer (score 0):

`Autocomplete` allow you to manage the render of your element. You may start from this point and try to make a custom render function. You just have to specify a render function in the configuration like :

```
$( "#customerAutocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    ... 
    _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        return $("<li>")
        .attr("data-value", item.value)
        .append($("<a>").html(item.label))
        .appendTo(ul);
    },
    ...
});
```

You can `console.debug` the item to check if it contains your text with accent.